# Automapper: DISALLOW auto-creation of maps NOT specifically mapped?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, automapper

Currently using AutoMapper V7.01 and have been using it delightfully for years.

Today, however, I uncovered something VERY surprising. Evidently, mappings can be created "dynamically" even if they do not exist in the profile. I'd like to confirm if there is a way to turn this off. I've checked the docs but can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Wondering -- would adding line in `Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression` like  `CreateMissingTypeMaps = False` be the answer? I would have thought that FALSE would have been the default, but maybe not...

I'd rather have an error occur for a missing map than to suffer the alternative. Here's what happens:

*Here's a snippet of my mapping profile:*

```
Imports AutoMapper
Public Class MappingProfile
    Inherits Profile
    Public Sub New()
        CreateMap(Of MenuItem, MenuItem)()
        CreateMap(Of MenuItemSize, MenuItemSize)()
        CreateMap(Of MenuItemChoice, MenuItemChoice)()
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

*It is initialized like this:*

```
Private Sub InitiatizeAutoMapper()
    Dim config As New Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression : With config
        .AddProfile(Of MappingProfile)()
    End With
    Mapper.Initialize(config)
End Sub
```

*And implemented like this:*

```
 Private Sub CopyMenuItemChoices(menuSetup As MenuCopyData, dbSrc As DataContext, dbTgt As DataContext)
     Dim srcRecs = From b In dbSrc.MenuItemChoices Where b.MenuId = menuSetup.SrcMenuId
     For Each srcRec As MenuItemChoice In srcRecs
         Dim newRec = Mapper.Map(Of MenuItemChoice)(srcRec)
         newRec.MenuId = menuSetup.TgtMenuId
         dbTgt.MenuItemChoices.InsertOnSubmit(newRec) : dbTgt.SubmitChanges()
         WriteXrefRec(menuSetup, srcRec.Id, newRec.Id, Enums.DbTableType.MenuItemChoice, dbSrc, dbTgt)
     Next
     dbSrc.SubmitChanges()
 End Sub
```

**The problem is** (was until I added the specific mapping) that, if the line in the profile

```
CreateMap(Of MenuItemChoice, MenuItemChoice)()
```

**DIDN'T** exist, Automapper would create a "dynamic" (I suppose) map for mapping MenuItemChoice --> MenuItemChoice. The problem comes in that when this happens and when it is implemented with

```
Dim newRec = Mapper.Map(Of MenuItemChoice)(srcRec)
newRec.MenuId = menuSetup.TgtMenuId
dbTgt.MenuItemChoices.InsertOnSubmit(newRec) : dbTgt.SubmitChanges()
```

the source record "srcRec" is "linked" to the target record instead of just copied and any changes made to the target (like inserting it into the database and submitting it) changes, for example, the Id value of the SOURCE record as well as the target record. You see the problem... :-(

Am I on the right track with `CreateMissingTypeMaps = False`?

**UPDATE:** Adding `CreateMissingTypeMaps = False` to the config did **NOT** work to fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false on the global configuration, not on some profile.